# How to find an HTML element based on text and then assign an ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have the following test code:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<DT>change me dynamically</DT>
<DD>
<input class=" text" type="text"  name="contact_details"  value=""  id="contact_details" >
<P CLASS="descr"></P>
</DD>

<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {
    //loop thorugh all controls.  find all labels (nodeType 1.  Find the "change my dynamically" text.  assign ID to control for use later.)
        $("*").contents().each(function() {
            if(this.nodeType == 1)
                this.nodeValue = this.nodeValue.replace("change me dynamically", "bingo!  you found me!");
                $(this).attr("id","theid");
            alert(this.nodeValue);
        });
 });

$('#theid').click(function() {
    alert('you did it!');
});
 </script>
```

Here's what I'm trying to do:

1. Locate the  that has the "change me dynamically" text in it.
2. Assign the  an ID like "id=theid"

I'm assuming the nodeType for the  is one because I changed the code so that I did have an ID assigned right from the start, and then rigged up an onclick event... like so:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<DT id="theid">change me dynamically</DT>
<DD>
<input class=" text" type="text"  name="contact_details"  value=""  id="contact_details" >
<P CLASS="descr"></P>
</DD>
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {
    //loop thorugh all controls.  find all labels (nodeType 1.  Find the "change my dynamically" text.  assign ID to control for use later.)
        $("*").contents().each(function() {
            if(this.nodeType == 1)
                this.nodeValue = this.nodeValue.replace("change me dynamically", "bingo!  you found me!");
                $(this).attr("id","theid");
            alert(this.nodeValue);
        });
 });

$('#theid').click(function() {
    alert(this.nodeType);
});
 </script>
```

The alert command shows "1" as the nodeType. 
But I'm obviously doing something wrong because I'm not able to get the text to change.

One other comment - i know that I could find all  items instead of getting all the contents... but I will be using similar logic for other element types, not just s. 
Thanks.

**EDIT 1**

There's a lot more HTML than what I've shown you... here's the full HTML:

```
<div id="page">
    <div id="header">
        <div class="leader">
            <a href="#Content" class="hide">[Skip to main content]</a>
        </div>
        <div id="logo">
            <div class="leader"></div>
            <a href="/">home</a> | 
            <a href="">about</a>
            </p></span>
        <div class="tailer"></div>
    </div>  <!-- header -->

    <div id="main">
        <div class="leader">
        </div>

        <div id="nav">
            <div class="leader">
                <h3 class="hide">[Main menu]</h3>
            </div>

            <ul>
                <li>Applications
                    <ul>
                        <li class='selected'><a class='selected' href="">Voicemail</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>

            <div class="tailer">
            </div>
        </div>  <!-- nav -->

        <a name="Content"></a>

<div id="content">
    <div class="leader">
    </div>



<form action="" method="POST">
<input class=" hidden" type="hidden"  name="redir"  value="" >
<input class=" hidden" type="hidden"  name="id"  value=""  readonly="true" >
<DT>Mobile Number</DT>
<DD>
<input class="testclass text" type="text"  name="mobile_number"  value="5371"  id="mobile_number"  readonly="false" >
</DD>
<DT>Rule Name</DT>
<DD>
<input class=" text" type="text"  name="rulename"  value="" >
<P CLASS="descr">Give this rule a name</P>
</DD>
<DT>Rule Type:</DT>
<DD>
<select name="ruletypes"  id="ruletypes" ><option  selected value="" ></option></select>
<P CLASS="descr"></P>
</DD>
<DT>When to use this rule</DT>
<DD>
<select name="rule_condition"  id="rule_condition" ><option  selected value="" ></option></select>
<P CLASS="descr"></P>
</DD>
<DT>What&#39;s the person&#39;s number?</DT>
<DD>
<input class=" text" type="text"  name="caller_id_number"  value=""  id="caller_id_number" >
<P CLASS="descr"></P>
</DD>
<DT>Start Time</DT>
<DD>
<input class=" text" type="text"  name="start_time"  value=""  id="start_time" >
<P CLASS="descr"></P>
</DD>
<DT>End Time</DT>
<DD>
<input class=" text" type="text"  name="end_time"  value=""  id="end_time" >
<P CLASS="descr"></P>
</DD>
<input class=" hidden" type="hidden"  name="user_id"  value="1"  readonly="true" >
<DT>Contact Type</DT>
<DD>
<select name="contact_types"  id="contact_types" ><option  selected value="" ></option></select>
<P CLASS="descr"></P>
</DD>
<DT>change me dynamically</DT>
<DD>
<input class=" text" type="text"  name="contact_details"  value=""  id="contact_details" >
<P CLASS="descr"></P>
</DD>
<DT> Order</DT>

<DT></DT><DD><input class="submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="Create Rule">
</DD>
</FORM></DL>
    <div class="tailer">
    </div>
</div>  <!-- content -->

    </div> <!-- main -->

    <div id="footer">
        <div class="leader">
        </div>
        <div class="tailer">
        </div>
    </div> <!-- footer -->
</div> <!-- page -->
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this?

```
$('body :contains("change me dynamically")').text(function(_, text){
    return text.replace(/change me dynamically/, "bingo!  you found me!");
}).attr('id', 'theId');
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/XuPQy/)**

Using **[:contains](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/)** to select the elements that has the particular text and then use the `.text()` callback to return the modified text.

Also note that while assigning `id` as the same one if there are multiple elemens with the same context you will end up creating your html with duplicate id.

Also you make sure you place the click event binding inside `document.ready` and after this logic, so that the event is bound correctly to the element with that id.

**Edit**

Based on your update:

```
$('body :contains("change me dynamically")').contents().each(function () {
    var exp = /change me dynamically/;
    if (this.nodeValue && exp.test(this.nodeValue)) {
        var $parent = $(this).parent().attr('id', 'theId');
        $parent.text(function(_, text){
           return  text.replace(exp, "bingo!  you found me!");
        }); 
    }
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/j9mf8/)**

If you will have just one instance then(assuming since you are adding id)

```
var exp = /change me dynamically/;
$('body :contains("change me dynamically")').last().text(function (_, text) {
    return text.replace(exp, "bingo!  you found me!");
}).attr('id', 'theId');
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sBgNg/)**

Comment: PSL, thats a cool snippet of code.  The only trouble is that it's replacing text in multiple areas.. not just the one element.  I made sure that I only have one element with the text "change my dynamically".  I've updated my code so you can see more of the big picture....

Comment: @markli really. could you replicate in a fiddle. i dont think it will replace anything but there is a contains. http://jsfiddle.net/8mFbe/

Comment: i pasted the code from my "Edit 1" section in my post into your fiddle... and i can recreate the problem. it changes my form and all its fields into a stream of text.

Comment: If you are sure only one instance would be there then: It can be made simple like this. http://jsfiddle.net/sBgNg/

Comment: PSL, hi there.  The first updated demo works... where we are looping through to find each element that contains the text "change me dynamically".  However, the second example using .last doesn't.  It's ok though.  I'll just use the first example.

Comment: PSL, can you explain this line of code in your example:  if (this.nodeValue && exp.test(this.nodeValue)) {

Comment: @markli it is to check if the nodeValue is available(for textnodes) and a regular expression test for the string just for 100% check match... so that only required value is evaluated a replaced. Also Javascript replace with regexp rather than just the string....

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the text is actually a separate node of type `TEXT_NODE` (3), which is a child of the `DT` element node. The nodeValue on the element is always going to be null. You need to modify the nodeValue of the text node.

If you really want to implement the code in this way, I would suggest looking for the `TEXT_NODE`, checking if it contains the text you want to match, replace the text, and then update the id of the parent node.

```
if (this.nodeType == this.TEXT_NODE) {
  if (this.nodeValue.indexOf("change me dynamically") != -1) {
    if (this.parentNode.tagName != 'SCRIPT') {
      this.nodeValue = this.nodeValue.replace("change me dynamically", 
        "bingo!  you found me!");
      $(this.parentNode).attr("id","theid");
      console.log(this.parentNode.tagName);
    }
  }
}
```

I've also added a check to make sure you don't try to match the text inside the `SCRIPT` tag if your script is inline.

Also note that if you want to set a click handler on the `$('#theid')` node, you should do that inside the `$(document).ready` function. Otherwise at the time you are trying to set handler, the `$(document).ready` function won't have run, so the id won't have been assigned yet.

Comment: James, thanks. I gave that a try.  Replaced my code inside the .each statement with yours.  but it doesn't work.  it doesn't change the text.  In fact, I get an error that says:  [16:45:34.445] TypeError: this.nodeValue.contains is not a function @ http://localhost/test/jquerynodetype.html:17.  Line 17 is this line:  " if (this.nodeValue.contains("change me dynamically")) {"

Comment: @markli Apparently `contains` doesn't work on some browsers. Have updated my answer to use `indexOf` instead.

Comment: James, I just tried your updated code... but it still doesn't work.  But it is assigning theid to something because in the console, i typed $('theid'); and i get a details back like "context : [object Document],
 selector : "#theid",

Comment: @markli Just realised why it was working for me and not you - I had script in a separate file. When the script is inline, the code also finds the text inside the script, so the id gets added to the script element. Haved updated my answer with a fix for that.

Comment: James, I just tried your code again and it's still not working.  =(  But it did rename some element to "theid"...

Comment: but your comment about the script is interesting... i'll try moving everything out to a separate file to see what happens.

Comment: @markli Here's a jsfiddle link with the working code: http://jsfiddle.net/ZCChy/ If that doesn't work for you, then I don't know what the problem is.